# Boost ring buffer indexing order, C++

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

When adding elements to [boost/circular_buffer.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) with push_back, is it possible to assume that the larger index means the later inserted element?

More precisely, in my case, to make the recent insertions more significant:

```
double weighted_running_average(const boost::circular_buffer<double> &x) 
{
          return (x[0] + 2*x[1] + 3*x[2]) / 6;
}
```

or would this result a non-predictable order of importance?

Comment: what index are you talking about? there is no index of any kind involved when you are using push_back

Comment: When accessing. The indices are 0, 1 and 2 in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `circular_buffer` is a sequence container so when you use `push_back` new element will be always accessible at highest index and the order of previously inserted elements will not change. If the buffer is full then first element will be erased and index of all existing elements reduced by 1.

Example ([online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gBetUPwcUzBeqFYP))

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ::boost::circular_buffer<int> x;
    x.set_capacity(2);
    x.push_back(0);
    x.push_back(1);
    std::cout << x[0]; // 0
    std::cout << x[1]; // 1
    x.push_back(2);
    std::cout << x[0]; // 1
    std::cout << x[1]; // 2
    return 0;
}
```